# Rails HABTM middle values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have to following relationship:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :courses
end
```

Then I have the following table:

```
create_table :courses_users, :force => true, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :course_id
  t.integer :middle_value
end
```

How can I access (edit/update) the middle value in the many to many record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HABTM should be used to only store the relation. If you have any fields you want to store in the relation, you should create another model, eg. `CourseSignup`. You would then use this model to create a `has_many :through => :course_signups` relation, so your models would look like this:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_signups
  has_many :users, :through => :course_signups
end

class CourseSingup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_signups
  has_many :courses, :through => :course_signups
end
```

Then you can add your `middle_value` in the `CourseSignup` model.

You can find more details in [the guide to ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association).

Answer (score 1):

You want a [`has_many :though`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association), not a HABTM.

A HABTM does not have a join model, but a `has_many :through` does. Something like:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :users, :through => :enrollments
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, :through => :enrollments
end
```